# Rails: Show search results based on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm using "mongoid_search" to power a search on the index page of my app.

The url, which returns results looks something like: "/profiles?utf8=✓&profile_search=San+Antonio%2C+TX"

How would I go about getting /location/sanantonio-tx to return the same results as the search url?

Basically, anything after "location" should be converted into the "profile_search" query string.

Also, is it possible to keep the URL the same? (e.g.: '/location'san-antonio-tx" url will not change into the query string)

Comment: Are you looking to go from [http://example.com/location/sanantonio-tx](http://example.com/location/sanantonio-tx) to [http://example.com/profiles?utf8=✓&profile_search=San+Antonio%2C+TX](http://example.com/profiles?utf8=✓&profile_search=San+Antonio%2C+TX)? And what do you mean by "keep the URL the same"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your provided code, it seems that the search is performed in the "index" action of the "profiles" controller. If this is the case, you can create a new route :

```
#config/routes.rb
match '/location/:profile_search' => 'profiles#index'
```

This will call the "index" action of the "profiles" controller, while providing everything that's after the "/location/" part of the url as a parameter named "profile_search"

For more info : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks almathie. That's what I was looking for. I do need to refine it a bit though. For example, "/location/san-antonio-tx" should search against three keywords (san,antonio and tx) in "profile_search". With the code you provided it searches "san-antonio-tx" as one keyword. Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Ok, looks like I answered my own question. Putting the "-" in between word in the url makes it work. "san-antonio-tx" will be processed as 3 keywords. Thanks again, almathie.